# Mascara em campos Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, rails4, mask, gem

Galera estou apanhando pra uma coisa teoricamente simples, estou querendo por uma mascara de data no meu `application.js`:

```
//= require maskedinput
jQuery(function($){
$("‪#‎datadoacao‬").mask("99/99/9999");
});
```

No meu partial de form:

```
<%= f.text_field :data_doacao, id: 'datadoacao' %>
```

E estou usando a gem `'maskedinput-rails'`.

Em meu template faço a seguinte chamada

Então eu importei o javascript direto no application.html.erb

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'maskedinput' %>
```

Alguém sabe o porque de não esta funcionando?

**Obs:** adicionei o arquivo maskedinput em `assests/javascript`

Comment: Algum erro no console?

Comment: No seu console do rails nao traz nenhuma mensagem de erro?

Answer (score 1):

Então eu importei o javascript direto no application.html.erb

`<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'maskedinput' %>`

Answer (score 1):

Como você já fez o `require` em seu `application.js`, certifique-se que fez o *require* também do `JQuery`

```
//= require maskedinput
//= require jquery
jQuery(function($){
   $("‪#‎datadoacao‬").mask("99/99/9999");
});
```

Seu `javascript_include_tag` já contém ele, então basta:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
```

Confiram também seu console de erros, caso esteja utilizando o Chrome basta pressionar **F12** e selecionar a aba **console**.

Se tiver tudo OK, deve aparecer algo como:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Caso tenha algum erro, algo como:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não sei se foi muito básico, mas você exibir alguma mensagem de erro pode ajudar muito no diagnóstico do problema.

Answer (score 1):

Olá, o que pode fazer também é verificar se o elemento está ficando com o id que você inseriu, o que eu uso geralmente é o seguinte:

```
<%= f.text_field :data_doacao, input_html: {'id': 'idQueQuer'} %>
```

Mas inspecione o elemento e confira se está com o id correto.

Answer (score 1):

Opa, cara, da olhada no MEIOMASK, eu gosto dele, e acho ele respectivamente simples... Eu baixei neste repositório (https://github.com/johnvoloski/meiomask-rails), o funcionamento é mais ou menos como abaixo:

```html
'z': /[a-z]/,
'Z': /[A-Z]/,
'a': /[a-zA-Z]/,
'*': /[0-9a-zA-Z]/,
'/': /[/]/,
'n': /[0-9]/,
'@': /[0-9a-zA-ZçÇáàãâéèêíìóòôõúùü]/

$('#datadoacao‬').setMask({mask: "nn/nn/nnnn"});
```

Espero que ajude